# How to convert WGS84 to NAD83 using R?

Tags: r, image, wgs84

Is there any way to "convert an IMG format image from WGS84 to NAD83" **using R programming**?

**Input image:**

Name:`LST_2011-03-30_WGS.img`

Format: `IMG (ERDAS)`

Projection: `UTM, Zone 12`

Spheroid: `WGS 84`

Datum: `WGS 84`

---

**Output image:**

Name:`LST_2011-03-30_NAD.img`

Format: `IMG (ERDAS)`

Projection: `UTM, Zone 12`

Spheroid: `GRS 1980`

Datum: `NAD 83`

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45263/converting-geographic-coordinate-system-in-r) will help.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use the package `gdalUtils` which assumes that the user has a working GDAL on their system. If the "gdalUtils_gdalPath" option has been set (usually by gdal_setInstallation), the GDAL found in that path will be used. If nothing is found, gdal_setInstallation will be executed to attempt to find a working GDAL that has the right drivers as specified with the "of" (output format) parameter.*

More on [inside-r.org](http://www.inside-r.org/node/229346).

Here the function `gdalwarp()` seems to do the job:

```
gdalwarp(srcfile="/your/path/LST_2011-03-30_WGS.img", #source file
         dstfile="/your/path/LST_2011-03-30_NAD.img", #destination file
         s_srs="+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84", #input spatial reference
         t_srs="+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80") #output spatial reference
```

**N.b.:** Since I dont have your images, I couldn't make sure that it really works with the above provided parameters. However I tested it with another .tif raster and other spatial reference systems and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
library(raster)
r <- raster('LST_2011-03-30_WGS.img')

## crs is normally defined, see
r
## but if it is not, you can set it
## crs(r) <- "+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84"

# set up an output RasterLayer
x <- raster(r)
crs(x) <- "+proj=utm +zone=12 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80"

# compute    
x <- projectRaster(r, x)
```

Comment: You really have to specify all the parameters, huh? Surprised there's not a much more elegant solution like `crs(map,name="NAD_1983_StatePlane_Pennsylvania_South_FIPS_3702_Feet")` that doesn't require me to know all that.

Comment: How is it easy, or easier, to know `"NAD_1983_StatePlane_Pennsylvania_South_FIPS_3702_Feet"`? Either way, this website makes it all quite easy to discover: http://spatialreference.org/

Comment: It is admittedly long. But for me, at least, the named CRS always has many anchors to my specific application--when I'm making maps in Michigan, it's `NAD_1983_StatePlane_Michigan...`. This is more intuitive (to me) than the list mentioned. Anyway, the link you provided is a great reference; thanks!